# split values from columns and generate sequence number

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I have two columns in a df. each column has multiple values in 1 row.I want to split each value in a new row  in another table and generate sequence number. given data is

```
x                                           y
76.25, 345.65                           87.12,96.45
78.12,35.1,98.27                       85.23,65.2,56.63
```

new df should be like this

```
x                  76.25
y                  87.12
sequence number      1
x                    345.65
y                    96.45
sequence number       2
x                     78.12
y                      85.23
sequence number         1
x                       35.1
y                      65.21
sequence number         2
x                     98.27
y                     56.63
sequence number         3
```

all values are strings. I have no idea how should I do it.Should I write a function or there is any command in dataframe? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `iterrows()` + `concat()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ('76.25,345.65', '78.12,35.1,98.27'),
    'y': ('87.12,96.45', '85.23,65.2,56.63')
})


def get_parts():
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        x = row['x'].split(',')
        y = row['y'].split(',')
        for index, _ in enumerate(x):
            #  len(x) must be equal len(y)...
            yield 'x', x[index]
            yield 'y', y[index]
            # generate number after each splitted item
            yield 'sequence number', index + 1


# generate Series from parts and union into new dataframe
new_df = pd.concat([
    pd.Series([p[1]], [p[0]])
    for p in get_parts()
])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user19 you can use [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to convert dataframe into `records` and write them into any `db`.  Also you can write data into `csv` and use a cli tool for inserting. There are many examples on the net. Good luck ;)

Comment: @user19 just ask a new question. Add a table structure, dataframe and expected result in db. I'm sure you'll get fast answer with explanations.